# aggregate rows using datatable

Tags: datatable, grouping, aggregate

My data looks like below and I would like to group it by zip. Along with the grouping I would like the lower, avg, upper, sum of idk, and avgDiff columns. The two calculated fields would be the Total Count by zip and sum of 'idk' (the table below this one). I would specifically like to use DataTable for this....thank you.

zip     lower avg    upper RISK idk diff  avgDiff total
1: 12007 -170.3723 592 1354.372 676   0   84 137.2903 123
2: 12007 -170.3723 592 1354.372 828   1  236 137.2903 123
3: 12007 -170.3723 592 1354.372 627   1   35 137.2903 123
4: 12009 -150.3723 300 1200.372 770   1  178 125.2903 456
5: 12007 -170.3723 592 1354.372 770   1  178 137.2903 123
6: 12010 -100.3723 200 1100.372 893   1  301 300.2903 890

desired result
    zip   lower    avg  upper   zipCount   avgDiff  sumidk
1: 12007 -170.3723 592 1354.372 4   137.2903      3
2: 12009 -150.3723 300 1200.372 1   125.2903      1
3: 12010 -100.3723 200 1100.372 1   300.2903      1

The lower, avg, upper, and avgDiff will be the same within the zip.

So far I have DT[, .(zipcount =.N), by = zip]....which is grouping zip and giving me the total zips (rows), but I'm getting stuck at this point.

thank you

Comment: I have added the fields I need by zip, but still have not grouped the zips using this code:  DT[, zipcnt := .N, by = zip]  [,sumidk := sum(idk), by = zip]  [,
            .(zip,lower,avg,upper,avgDiff,zipcnt,sumidk)]  if someone has a way to select only distinct rows by zip, lower, avg, upper, avgDiff, zipcnt, and sumidk I will get my desired results. However, i feel there is a much easier way. I know could use dplyer's count function but want to do this using datatable.

Comment: correction: the count function in dplyr will not accomplish what I want. It will only count unique values among selected variables. I believe I can use the distinct function in the J section of datatable.  I will let you know what happens...

Comment: here is my answer, please share any better/different solutions:        ninefive[, zipcnt := .N, by = zip][,sumidk := sum(idk), by = zip][,
            .(zip,lower,avg,upper,avgDiff,zipcnt,sumidk)][,
              distinct(zperform)]